# Retain super user rights after an apk application update

Tags: android, apk

I have an app that updates automatically by downloading the latest apk and prompting the user to upgrade (all the app data remains). However the app requires Superuser access and prompts the user for permission after every upgrade. Is there a way to tell the Superuser app to retain the rights?

Upgrading seems to be a bit strange, all the app data and settings remain intact (as described during the upgrade process) but the launcher icon disappears. Any thoughts on that as well?

Comment: While I have no real evidence that it's the case, I could easily see the logic in a Superuser-authorizing program deciding to re-require user approval if it detects that an app has been updated or modified since last approved by the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The end-user needs to configure this in their SU app. For example, SuperSU has an option that allows users to choose whether they want their preference (grant/deny/prompt) to persist when an app is updated, or if they want the preference to be reset with each update.

Also, if you are using Google Play, be warned that your method of updating is prohibited by the [Developer Program Policies](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html):

> An app downloaded from Google Play may not modify, replace or update
>   its own APK binary code using any method other than Google Play's
>   update mechanism.

Comment: The application in question runs in a kiosk mode and is exclusive for the tablet, so Google Play is not involved in any way. Adjusting SuperSU on each tablet fixed the problem. However, the "superuser" app (by ChainsDD) does not support a similar feature.